# Where can I find papers on the geology of the Wastach Range in Utah

Tags: sedimentology, metamorphism, literature-request

I am looking for papers on the stratigraphy, geochronology and/or compositional make up of the Wastach Range and its formations. I prefer a broad overview paper and I can't seem to find one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[This report](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/cir296) on the stratigraphy is probably a good place to start.

Additonally, searching Google Scholar for Wasatch Range geochronology brings up a number of papers on the geochronology of specific formations if you are interested in that.

Comment: I did find that one! I was concerned that the naming conventions were outdated since I have done research on other mountain ranges and have seen that formations either got renamed, reclassified or split up into further units. If this isn't the case then I will start looking into that USGS paper.